# How do I start the chinese electric motorcycle that I purchased from China?

Tags: starting

I purchased a electric motorcycle from China but, after removing the bike from the shipping carton and inserted the key there wasn't any power and once I connected it to the charger provided the bike has power but the power drains as soon as it is disconnected from the charger.

Comment: Buy a quality one.

Comment: It's possible there is some electrical insulation around the battery terminals as a safety measure during shipping. Or a battery connector was intentionally left disconnected, for the same reason.

Comment: It's also possible you got crap batteries.

Comment: a couple of pictures of the battery and its connectors will help in diagnosing this problem,if you measure the voltage on the battery terminals does the voltage change when you are charging the battery vs not charging it,(this will show if the battery is connected correctly to your mc).

Comment: Did it actually come with batteries?

Comment: How long did you charge it for? How long does the instructions say?

Comment: This cycle was almost certainly shipped in a state where it's "deactivated" so that power to the motor cannot happen in transit.  That would be a fire hazard.  You will need to read the follow the (hopefully) included instructions on how to set it up for first use.  If it didn't come with any instructions you should contact the seller or the manufacturer and get that.

Comment: Is there a fuse holder between the battery and the ignition barrel?